# Error al abrir formulario hijo MDI

Tags: c#, windows-forms, formularios, visual-studio-2015

que tal chic@s tengo un problema, al abrir un formulario MDI con un menustrip me abre bien la primera vez pero cuando lo cierro no me vuelve abrir y me lanza un error

este es el codigo del menu principal

```
  private void inscripcionHermanoToolStripMenuItem_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Inscripcion_Hermano AbrirForm = Inscripcion_Hermano.Abrir_hermano;
            AbrirForm.MdiParent = this;
            AbrirForm.Show();
        }
```

y este es el codigo del frm que se abre

```
        public static Inscripcion_Hermano Abrir_hermano
        {
            get
            {
                if (_Abrir_hermano == null)
                    _Abrir_hermano = new Inscripcion_Hermano();
                return _Abrir_hermano;
            }
        }
```

al abrirlo la primera vez me abre bien
[image: imagen delfmr abierto]

pero cuando lo cierro y lo abro nuevamente me sale este error

[image: erro lanzado]

[image: detalles error]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suscribete al evento FormClosed
[image]
y añade este código:

```
private void Inscripcion_Hermano_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
{
    _Abrir_hermano = null;
}
```

Comment: me sirvio amigo muchas gracias, solo una pregunta porque envia ese error ?

Comment: Al cerrar el formulario el objeto hace Dispose, se elimina, por tanto aparece un error si se intenta volver a utilizar. Poniendo ese valor a null al cerrar el formulario hago que se vuelva a llamar al new cuándo quieres abrirlo de nuevo.

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo !!!!